# Method overloading based on generic constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

Can I somehow have overloaded methods which differ only by generic type *constraints*?

This does not compile:

```
    void Foo<T>(T bar) where T : class
    {

    }

    void Foo<T>(T bar) where T : struct
    {

    }
```

Since these are "open" methods, the actual method should be closed/constructed/fully-defined when it's referenced elsewhere in code with a concretely-typed `T`, and then it would be clear which overload to call.

The obvious solution is not to overload them, but I'm wondering why this doesn't work in C#?

Additional question: If this is just a C# compiler constraint, does the IL allow such an overload?

Comment: This is a good question and one that hopefully gets answered by @EricLippert.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: yes, I always love a Jon Skeet answer, but this is also really Eric's bread and butter and so it's always interesting to see his answers to people when they say "why doesn't C# allow this?"

Comment: @Mike: Definetely because Eric will give an insider view being principal developer on the C# compiler team.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: exactly!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can I somehow have overloaded methods which differ only by generic type constraints?

No. It's not part of the method signature in terms of overloading, just like the return type isn't.

There are [*horrible*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround/) ways of "pseudo-overloading" in some cases, but I wouldn't recommend going down that path.

For more information, you might want to read:

- [My blog post on the topic](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/)
- [Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx)

Comment: Your blog post linked under the *horrible* link is *exactly* what I was trying to achieve, method overload for a class, value and a nullable with the same name.

Comment: @BorisB., one note is that if Jon is calling it _horrible_ please **dont** implement it!

Comment: The "horrible" code could be improved somewhat by defining a dummy interface with a struct constraint, and using that as a dummy parameter rather than a `T?`.  Unlike e.g. a `Drawing.Rectangle?` which would take 20 bytes, the interface would only take four.  As for it being "horrible", it confines the nastiness to a small helper method and in most contexts the performance hit shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @supercat: It still involves the overloaded method having a parameter solely for the purpose of signature differentation, which counts as horrible to me. Renaming the method is a much better option, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I share your distaste for passing a dummy parameter, but in cases where the semantics of the method should be the same regardless of parameter type (e.g. `bool TryConvert<T>(o as Object, out T result)`) having the compiler auto-select among struct-only, class-only, and universal methods would seem cleaner than requiring calling code to use different names (especially since there would be no diagnostic if a slower universal method was used where a faster one could have been inferred).

Comment: @JonSkeet At least at CLR level return type is a part of method signature. CLR supports overloading by return type only and F# uses it, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.

Generic constraints are not considered to be part of the method signature for purposes of overloading.

If you want to allow both value types and reference types, why constrain at all?

Comment: To avoid jumping through the hoops of `if (typeof(T)...` (which can/should be resolved statically btw. and optimized away). Also it's not just class/struct combo, it's also `where T:Foo/where T:Bar`.

Comment: The fact that a method is available for use with a reference type or with a value type does not imply that the same method should be used in either case.  As a simple example, suppose one wanted to write a method `bool TryCasting<T>(object it, out T result);`.  If `T` is a class type, the method can try `it as T`; if it's a value type, `it as T?`.  If `T` can't be inferred either way, one may have to use Reflection to select a method, but if it can be inferred at compile doing, doing so would boost performance.

Answer (score 0):

An update. In C# 7.3 generic constraints are now part of overload decision.

So, this code will compile:

```
class Animal { } 
class Mammal : Animal { } 
class Giraffe : Mammal { }
class Reptile : Animal { } 

static void Foo<T>(T t) where T : Reptile { }
static void Foo(Animal animal) { }
static void Main() 
{ 
    Foo(new Giraffe()); 
}
```

Comment: Sort of... If there are method groups that contain generic constraints that aren't satisfied, these are removed. It still doesn't allow the OP to write the code in the question though, the constraints are still not part of the signature. In other words, the code in the question still doesn't compile in C# 7.3. It works here because the method signatures differ. So while your answer is factual true, it is not a good answer to this question because the question revolves around the declaration, not the overload resolution.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct _Val_Trait<T> where T:struct { }
struct _Ref_Trait<T> where T:class { }

static void Foo<T>(T bar, _Ref_Trait<T> _ = default(_Ref_Trait<T>)) where T:class
{
    Console.WriteLine("ref");
}

static void Foo<T>(T bar, _Val_Trait<T> _ = default(_Val_Trait<T>)) where T:struct
{
    Console.WriteLine("val");
}

static void Main() 
{
    Foo(1);            // -->"val"
    Foo(DateTime.Now); // -->"val"
    Foo("");           // -->"ref"

    //but:
    //Foo(null); - error: type cannot be inferred
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked, as it requires the introduction of new types, and requires methods whose signatures are in fact _different_. The question asked here involves methods having the same signature, but with different generic type constraints.